# Querying backwards association with JPA QL in a grails 3 Data Service, MissingMethodException executeQuery on Object?

Tags: jpa, grails-orm, jpql, grails3, grails-3.3

In a database, that gathers authors and their books, we add the books by an `Author` as `Book` instances.

However, an `Author` may have books that have not yet been added to the database. This is why we have an outside sanity counter, telling us how many books an `Author` actually has published. If the `numberOfKnownBooks` is equal to the number of `Book` instances in the database, then we consider that we have an `Author`'s complete bibliography.

[image: Data Model]

An SQL query to obtain all the `Authors` whose bibliography is complete would be written like this in SQL:

```
select author.id, count(*)
from book inner join author on book.author_id=author.id
group by author.number_Of_Known_Books, author.id
having count(*) = author.number_Of_Known_Books
```

The difficulty here is that the join points in the opposite direction, and that normal examples usually show how to create a query to obtain `Books` joined with `Authors`, not the other way around.

I have found some articles in stackoverflow explaining how to do something like this in plain JPQL (minus the group by ... having complication) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354150/jpa-hibernate-inverse-join-on-unidirectional-onetoone-association), but doing this in the DSL expected by the `@Query` annotation in a Data Service in GORM 6.1+, I get an exception, occurring in the dungeons of generated code by an AST, saying that it can't find method `executeQuery` on `java.lang.Object`. This is a reasonable complaint, but I have no idea why it is happening. No way to step debug this code unfortunately.

This is my Data Service:

```
import grails.gorm.services.Query
import grails.gorm.services.Service


@Service
abstract class AuthorService {

    @Query("""
            select a.*, count(a.id)
            from ${Book b} join ${b.author} a
            group by a.numberOfKnownBooks, a.id
            having count(*) = a.numberOfKnownBooks
""")
    abstract List<Author> retrieveCompleteAuthors()
}
```

**UPDATE**: removed useless annotations @GrailsCompileStatic and @Transactional as per jeff's instructions

**FULL SOLUTION**, with the right JPQL query:

```
@Service(Author)
abstract class AuthorService {
    @Query("""
        select auth from ${Author auth}  where auth.id in (
            select a.id
            from ${Book b} join ${b.author} a
            group by a.numberOfKnownBooks, a.id
            having count(*) = a.numberOfKnownBooks
        ) 
""")
    abstract List<Author> retrieveCompleteAuthors()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that isn't really the HQL you want but that is a separate issue.  The error you asked about should go away if you do something like this...

```
import grails.gorm.services.Query
import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Author)
abstract class AuthorService {

    @Query('''
            select a.*, count(a.id)
            from ${Book b} join ${b.author} a
            group by a.numberOfKnownBooks, a.id
            having count(*) = a.numberOfKnownBooks
    ''')
    abstract List<Author> retrieveCompleteAuthors()
}
```

Comment: The `@Transactional` and `@GrailsCompileStatic` are superfluous in this particular case so they can be removed.  The real issue was `@Service(Author)` vs `@Service`.

Comment: My Query is still failing, but You solved the question I was not able to solve by myself: getting Gorm to execute my query. For that, I'm crediting you. I will update my query when I get it right.

Comment: replacing @Service with @Service(Author) did it.

Comment: If you replace your `"""` with `'''` the query will at least execute.  Unclear if it is correct, but it at least becomes valid then.

Comment: The problem with `"""` is that is a Groovy String with interpolation and you have expressions like `${Book b}` and `${b.author}` in the String.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doubles quotes is what I am supposed to use: http://guides.grails.org/grails-gorm-data-services/guide/index.html#japqlQuery

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.